# spring boot @scheduled triggered after the time expected

Tags: spring-boot

I try to trigger a task every day at 7h45 in spring boot by this way

```
@Scheduled(cron = "45 7 * * * ?")
public void method() {....}
```

And I saw this morning that it triggered at around 9h09.
I checked that server time correspond to the time displayed on my computer. Furthermore the server is running on windows
So Why this difference of time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element in Spring cron expressions are seconds.
So I assume that it was run at 9:07:45

This would be the correct expression:

```
0 45 7 * * ?
```

Check out: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but with your expression, the application complains that there is only 5 fields and 6 fields are expected

Comment: Sorry I've updated my answer. I forgot that Spring has seconds.